# Матрица : вывести положительные числа. Если таковых нет - вывести надпись об отсутствии таковых чисел - C++

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Как вывести надпись об отсутствии положительных чисел в данном коде?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    int i, j, n, m;
    int mas[30][30];
    double s1, s2;

    cout << "Размер матрицы n \n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Размер матрицы m \n";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "\n\n";


    srand(time(0));


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            mas[i][j] = rand() % 101 - 50;


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << mas[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // N - кол - во элементов массива
    { 
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (mas[i][j] > 0)
                cout << "Положительные числа : " << mas[i][j] << " ";

        }       
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `cout << "Положительные числа отсутствуют" << endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool hasPositive = false;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // N - кол - во элементов массива
{ 
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (mas[i][j] > 0)
        {
            cout << "Положительные числа : " << mas[i][j] << " ";
            hasPositive = true;
        }
    }       
}

if (!hasPositive) cout << "Положительных чисел нет\n";
```

Кстати, так, как у вас написано - вы будете выводить `Положительные числа :` для каждого положительного числа...

Comment: Да, я знаю, что для каждого числа. А можно как-нибудь иначе сделать без  использования "bool hasPositive = false;" подобного?

Comment: Ну введите переменную для отслеживания количества выведенных чисел. Или функцию для чтения с экрана - а не было ли выведено сообщение о положительном числе? Ну или заново все перепроверьте, найдите максимальное значение массива, и если оно больше нуля - значит, такое число было выведено... Могу набросать и еще более громоздкие способы, если простой путь - не для вас :)

Comment: Если уж так, то не надо. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> positiveValues;
...
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if ( mas[i][j] > 0 ) positiveValues.push_back( mas[i][j] );
    }
}
...
if ( !positiveValues.empty() ) {
    cout << "Положительные числа : ";
    for (auto value : positiveValues) {
        cout << value << " ";  
    }
    cout << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Положительные числа отсутствуют" << endl;
}
```